# making a react web app responsive - tips to help do it easily?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am currently working on a reactjs web app. I was wondering how do I make it responsive? Whenever I change the size of my browser, all my components get messed up and flow onto each other. How do I stop that from happening in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

"Responsive Design" is huge part/topic in development. In my opinion its a long term process to learn. The more you build projects, the more you can learn.

But there are lots of UI libraries/frameworks are available to make it easier. And fortunately every of them have a React Version. Here are some of them -

1. [ReactStrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/)
2. [Semantic UI React](https://react.semantic-ui.com/)
3. [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/)
4. [Chakra](https://chakra-ui.com/)
5. [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/)
6. [BaseWeb](https://baseweb.design/)

If you have time to learn more about responsive design, you can check out the official guidelines from [Responsive web design basics](https://web.dev/responsive-web-design-basics/).

Some common techniques you can follow -

- Try to set width and height of your layout with percentage(%) value or vw & vh.
- Use flexbox or grid.
- Use css media query and follow the standard breakpoints.
- If possible give your component max-width / max-height when necessary.
- You can build a BaseLayout component which has `max-width: 1920` and wrap other widgets with it. So, in a very big screen your app contains always width of 1920px.

Hope this will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive is a design technique - No libary or tool will do it for you, because you need to choose which elements get hidden or resized etc. Having said that, a framework such as [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) will make responsive design easier.

But you'll have to look around and learn the ropes - its a different methodology of web design.

Comment: How does bootstrap make it easier? Just curious

Comment: It looks after a lot of the CSS boilerplate/busy work and imposes reasonable defaults that  make responsive design easier. If you want to learn responsive design well, it actually might be easier to start without a framework and move over once you are up to speed.